# Python function chaining an unknown number of times

Tags: python, chaining

Is there a way in Python to chain the same function an unknown number of times on an object?

For example. If I wanted to chain the function `fn` on the object `obj` twice I'd have:

```
obj.fn(**kwargs1).fn(**kwargs2)
```

If I wanted to chain a `fn` five times I'd have:

```
obj.fn(**kwargs1).fn(**kwargs2).fn(**kwargs3).fn(**kwargs4).fn(**kwargs5)
```

Comment: While not important for the answer to the question, the use case is that I'm using an API which for each **line** of code will make a request to a server. I want to minimize the number of requests and so want to chain functions. But, I do not know at the outset the number of times I wish to chain the functions.

Comment: how does `fn` looks like?

Comment: You could use a recursive function with a counter and set the counter either manually or with an exit condition

Comment: how does fn looks like?  @Ian also do they change every time?

Comment: To add more detail to the problem statement: I'm using the Python wrapper for Gremlin. The object is a vertex, and the `fn` function definition is `property(name, value)`, which assigns a new property to that vertex in a graph. When the line of code executes, it sends the query to a Gremlin server and updates the specified vertex with a new property-value. (but all this is abstracted away)

Comment: So to answer your question, `fn` does not change each time, just the values passed into it

Comment: so you just want to call fn N number of times? And you mean "unknown" as in, not known when you write the code right? it is still parameterized by a variable right?

Comment: That's correct. I'll iterate over some list that specifies - per item - the number of times to call the function for each iteration, as well as the args to pass in to each `fn` call.

Comment: Can't you just use a for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use a simple for loop, which iterates over the list of arguments, and applies each argument to the object, and reassign the results back to the object

```
for args in list_of_args:

    obj = obj.fn(*args)
```

For example, I can use this logic to chain `string.replace` as follows

```
obj = 'aaaccc'
list_of_args = [['a','b'], ['c','d']]

for args in list_of_args:
    obj = obj.replace(*args)

print(obj)
```

And the output will be

```
bbbddd
```

Which is the same as doing `'aaabbb'.replace('a','b').replace('c','d')`

Or we can also perhaps use a recursive method, which takes in the object, and a counter which serves as an index of the current argument to be applied, and a number of times the function needs to run

```
#fn is either defined, or imported from outside
def chain_func(obj, counter, max_count):

    #If counter reaches max no of iterations, return
    if counter == max_count:
        return obj

    #Else recursively apply the function
    else:
        return chain_func(obj.fn(list_of_args[counter]), counter+1, max_count)

#To call it twice
list_of_args = [kwargs1, kwargs2]
chain_func(obj, 0, 2)
```

For example, I can use this logic to chain string.replace as follows

```
def chain_func(obj, counter, max_count):

    #If counter reaches max no of iterations, return
    if counter == max_count:
        return obj

    #Else recursively apply the function
    else:
        return chain_func(obj.replace(*list_of_args[counter]), counter+1, max_count)


list_of_args = [['a','b'], ['c','d']]
print(chain_func('aaaccc', 0, 2))
```

And the output will be

```
bbbddd
```